# Sharepoint Designer 2007 Email alert every 1st and 15th of the month

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How can I create an email alert(notification) using a List item in Sharepoint designer 2007?

These alerts will run every 1st and 15th of the month and should also trigger for the next coming months.